# Oozie Installation:Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile on project oozie-core:

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

Could you help me to resolve an oozie installation error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 486 source files to /opt/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/core/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /opt/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/dependency/HCatURIHandler.java:[273,47] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project oozie-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /opt/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/dependency/HCatURIHandler.java:[273,47] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I am running hadoop in Psedo-mode with mvn version:3.3.9, java:1.8, hadoop:2.7.2, oozie:4.2.0.

I have downloaded http://mirrors.whoishostingthis.com/apache/oozie/4.2.0/oozie-4.2.0.tar.gz/oozie-4.2.0.tar.gz and untarred it. I then ran ./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests from bin directory.

```
I have modified my hadoop-version and java-version in the pom.xml
<targetJavaVersion>1.8</targetJavaVersion>
<hadoop.version>2.7.2</hadoop.version>
<hive.version>1.2.1</hive.version>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have manually applied OOZIE-2305.01.patch (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2305) and it worked. (FYI, The release notes of "oozie 4.2.0" doesn't contain this patch)

So, modify the following java file wherever needed as per the patch: "/opt/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/dependency/HCatURIHandler.java" file.

After making the changes, I've restarted the installation from where it left by:
sudo mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile -rf :oozie-core

I hope this helps, let me know if you need any help in updating "HCateURIHandler.java"